# Certificate authority invalid

Tags: linux, ssl

We recently renewed our certs for our vhost domains:
`genietvanhetleven.org`
    newportandbeyond.org
`privustech.com`
    truthcourage.org

Chromium reports
`    NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Firefox reports
`    SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE

The sites open just fine in Konqueror.

---

1. I cleared the cache in Chromium and Firefox and shut down for the night. After a restart they all are now working under http but https is struck out.
2. We have Used Qualys:
   Qualys shows
   `For privustech.com:`
       Certificate #2 No SNI
   `Common names   genietvanhetleven.org   MISMATCH`
       Trusted    No   NOT TRUSTED
   `    Path #2: Not trusted (invalid certificate:

Where is this second cert coming from????

This and all the others get an "A" rating without any other errors.

=====

3. This may be due to CA cert issues. However, we have:
   `• Checked the CA certs, they are valid`
    • Checked file encoding, they are valid (us-ascii)
   ` • Redownloaded and installed the site and intermediate chain certificates.
4. We have checked the key-cert pairs, they are valid:
   openssl x509 -in _start.crt -text -noout
5. We have checked the chains, they are valid: 
   `# openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <vhost>_start_chain.crt`
       _start.crt _start.crt: OK
6. We have checked the validity dates, they are valid.
   `# openssl x509 -startdate -enddate -noout -in <vhost>_start.crt`
       notBefore=Jan 28 21:17:02 2017 GMT
   `    notAfter=Jan 28 21:17:02 2020 GMT
7. We have checked configuration files. they are valid:
   All have the same
   `ServerName privustech.com:993`
       ServerAdmin alavarre@privustech.com
   `SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs`
       SSLCACertificateFile
   `    /etc/ssl/certs/StartCom_Certification_Authority.pem
8. We have checked error logs:
   `X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch`
    But they *do* match.

So quite a mess. It was working fine until the OLD certs,expired, but we have installed the NEW certs, intermediate and CA certs and cleared the cache, so why is it addressing the old certs???

Comment: Long story short, your SSL provider is not a CA anymore: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/

Answer (score 1):

These are sites which use StartCom certificates.
Because of cheating attempts StartCom is no longer trusted by major browsers, at least Chrome and Firefox. For more details see

- [Mozilla: Distrusting New WoSign and StartCom Certificates](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/) in Firefox
- [Google: Distrusting WoSign and StartCom Certificates](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html) in Chrome
- [Apple: Blocking Trust for WoSign CA Free SSL Certificate G2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202858) in Safari
- [Despite revoked CA’s, StartCom and WoSign continue to sell certificates](https://ma.ttias.be/despite-revoked-cas-startcom-wosign-continue-sell-certificates/)

Comment: Thank you. At least I wasn't messing up the configuration. I've spent the day trying to install certbot under openSUSE Leap 42,1 without success. The dependency hell hinges on python-acme 0.10.1... Tomorrow is another day. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you again. I have solved the problem by moving to LetsEncrypt.

Several days of work but done. They offer CertBot, but I could not get it to work under openSUSE. OTOH Dehydrated worked just fine (after some learning pains)

https://letsencrypt.org/
https://www.aaflalo.me/2016/09/dehydrated-bash-client-lets-encrypt/